# C++ vector fuction "push_back()", what type return it?

Tags: c++, utf-8

I just code a program wich convert a string to uft8 value for each char

Example : a in utf8 decimal = 97/
5 in utf8 decimal = 53...

here my code :

```
    string word;//keyWord
    vector<__int8> tableau;//utfValueTab
    cout << "Entre un mot de passe : " << endl;
    cin >> word;
    
    //FONCTION CONVERTION STRING > UTF8 VALUE FOR EACH CHAR
    for (int a = 0; a < word.length(); a++) {
        __int8 utfValue = 0;
        for (short i = 0; i < 255 && word.at(a) != char(i); i++) {
            utfValue++;
        }
        tableau.push_back(utfValue);
        cout << tableau[a] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Voici votre mot de passe decoupe" << endl;
```

The problem is, tableau[a] return char and not __int8 value, and I don't understand why because my "tableau" is in __int8 like the uftValue.

So, the push_back function return just char and string value ?

Thanks you for help.

Comment: Sidenote: the return type of `push_back()` is [`void`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) and doesn't matter here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for awnsers, i will check it

Comment: That's it, __int8 can't be print, so I use short and it work now ! thanks yo

Answer (score 0):

Try the standard `uint8_t` instead of `__int8`.

Comment: I try it, and I just have char by char wich is print

Comment: generally all 8-bit data types stream as characters

Comment: fix that by casting it to int. `cout << int(tableau[a]) << endl;`